# MySQL 5.1.41: Does the MySQL User password expire like in Oracle?

Tags: mysql, database, change-password

I had never changed the password of my `root` user before and it's password has never expired. Now I have to change its password and I will be using this code to do it:

```
SET PASSWORD FOR 'root'@'localhost' = PASSWORD('StrongPassword');
SET PASSWORD FOR 'root'@'%' = PASSWORD('StrongPassword');
```

Will the password expire anytime soon? If so how can i query to know the expiry date?

**In Oracle, I use**

```
select
     ACCOUNT_STATUS
    ,USERNAME
    ,EXPIRY_DATE
from
    DBA_USERS
;
```

Is there anything like it in **MySQL** that I should be concerned about?

Comment: No, it doesn't expire.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That depends on the version of MySQL and how it is set up.  From the [MySQL docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/password-expiration-policy.html):

> MySQL enables database administrators to expire account passwords
>   manually, and to establish a policy for automatic password expiration

Also:

> Automatic password expiration is available in MySQL 5.7.4 and later.
>   The mysql.user table indicates for each account when its password was
>   last changed, and the server automatically treats the password as
>   expired at client connection time if it is past its permitted
>   lifetime. This works with no explicit manual password expiration.

By default the time is 0 so never expires (version 5.7.4) but the default in 5.7.10 is 360, and is measured in days.  It can be set to never expire if needed though

Comment: The MySQL version I'm using is 5.1.41

Comment: Then it won't expire user's passwords.  I can't find the documentation for 5.1 at the moment but it's not likely to have the option, certainly not unless you've set it up to have it if it is available

Answer (score 0):

You can check options file for `default_password_lifetime`

If you want to establish global policy, set this parameter to number of days you wish password to expire.

On single user you can run this:

```
ALTER USER 'johndoe'@'localhost' PASSWORD EXPIRE INTERVAL 30 DAY;
```